# Angular.JS + Require.JS - Accessing other directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using Angular.JS with Require.JS. My file structure is similar (simplified for the example) to below:

**main.js**

```
require( ['controllers', 'directives/priceBox', 'directives/slider'], function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

**app.js**

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
    return angular.module('myApp', []);
});
```

**directives/slider.js:**

```
define(['app', 'jquery-ui', 'directives/priceBox'], function (app) {
    'use strict';
    app.directive('slider', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<div id="slider"></div>',
            replace: true,
            require: 'priceBox',
            link: function(scope, el, attrs, priceBoxCtrl){

            }
        };
    });
});
```

**directives/priceBox.js**

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.directive('priceBox', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<div id="price">{{ price }}</div>',
            replace: true,
            controller: function ($scope) {
                console.log('Hi from controller');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

What I want here is to access `priceBox` controller in the `slider` directive. Yet, this code raise an `Error: No controller: priceBox` error.

Comment: Depending on your HTML layout, have you tried `require: '^priceBox'`?

Comment: @Marius Soutier, Yes, I did.